# Same Python code appears to have different performance characteristics

Tags: python, performance, cprofile

### Description

In my code to create `N` random strings of length `k`, a generator expression to create a random `k`-character string gets called either `N+1` or `(N+1)*k` (aka `N*k+N`) times. This appears to be happening with the [exact same code](https://pastebin.com/1u1j1ZUt) and I can switch back and forth seemingly non-deterministically by redefining the `chrs()` helper function. I suspect the profiler but don't have any clue as to the mechanism.

System details, in case they matter: CPython, Python 2.7.17 and Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Envy 15k (i7-4720)

### Reproducing the Issue

*Not a proper MCVE as I haven't been able to deterministically reproduce the issue; instead, running this will hopefully result in one of the two profiler outputs below. If you try running this in the REPL and redefining the `chrs()` function repeatedly using the same code, you might be able to get both profiler outputs.*

I wrote this `bits_strings()` function when benchmarking various ways of generating `N` (`num_strings`) random strings of length `k` (`len_string`):

```
import cProfile
import random
import string

def chrs(bits, len_string):
    return ''.join(chr((bits >> (8*x)) & 0xff) for x in range(len_string))

def bits_strings(num_strings, len_string):
    return list(
        chrs(random.getrandbits(len_string*8), len_string)
        for x in range(num_strings)
    )

cProfile.run('bits_strings(1000, 2000)')
```

To benchmark it, I used `cProfile.run()`.

When I ran the code the first time, it seemed decently fast:

```
cProfile.run('bits_strings(1000, 2000)')
         2005005 function calls in 0.368 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.970    1.970 <stdin>:1(bits_strings)
     1000    0.001    0.000    1.963    0.002 <stdin>:1(chrs)
     1001    0.001    0.000    1.970    0.002 <stdin>:2(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.970    1.970 <string>:1(<module>)
  2000000    0.173    0.000    0.173    0.000 {chr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1000    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.Random' objects}
     1000    0.178    0.000    1.953    0.002 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
     1001    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {range}
```

but later in the day:

```
cProfile.run('bits_strings(1000, 2000)')

         4005004 function calls in 1.960 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.961    1.961 <stdin>:1(bits_strings)
     1000    0.001    0.000    1.954    0.002 <stdin>:1(chrs)
  2001000    1.593    0.000    1.762    0.000 <stdin>:2(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.961    1.961 <string>:1(<module>)
  2000000    0.170    0.000    0.170    0.000 {chr}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1000    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'getrandbits' of '_random.Random' objects}
     1000    0.182    0.000    1.944    0.002 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
     1001    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {range}
```

The difference looks like it comes from the `<genexpr>`, which- from the `cumtime` and the location across various similar tests, I've inferred to be the one in `chrs()`. (My instinct is that `(chr((bits >> (8*x)) & 0xff) for x in range(len_string))` should be getting called `N` times, while `chr((bits >> (8*x)) & 0xff)` should be getting called `N*k` times).

So what's the difference between the two `bits_strings()` functions? When trying to find the difference in the code between the two attempts, I found none. In fact, I had a Python REPL session where I defined the functions, ran the profiler twice (the second time, to check whether this was a caching issue), and then re-defined the functions by using the up-arrow to retrieve my previously-entered code. It exhibited the same divergence: https://pastebin.com/1u1j1ZUt

### Theories & Thoughts

I suspect cProfile.

Switched between the "fast" and "slow" versions by redefining `chrs()` but had `cProfile.run()` get profiled by `cProfile.run()`. In both observed time *and*  per the outer `cProfile.run()`'s reporting, it looks like the inner `cProfile.run()` (the one that profiles `bits_strings()`) has been occasionally underreporting how long `bits_strings()` takes: https://pastebin.com/C4W4FEjJ

I also used `time.time()` before/after `cProfile.run('bits_strings(1000,1000))` calls and noticed a discrepancy between the "fast" profile `cumtime` and the actual wall-clock time taken when running the method.

But I'm still unclear on the mechanism.

- **Caching**: Same code, drastically different performance between runs could be a caching thing. However, the fast version was the first run I ever did with this code (although I'd run other code before in the same REPL session). And I can switch from slow to fast or fast to slow by simply redefining `chrs()` and `bits_strings()`, although whether or not I actually switch seems random. Also worth noting is that I've only been able to switch (afaict) by redefining the functions, not by simply rerunning them. So I'm not sure *what* would be cached or how it would change the # of `<genexpr>` calls by a factor of `k` upon redefining the function.
- **cProfile quirk**: I ran the same code without `cProfile.run()` and timed it by getting the current `time.time()` inside `bits_strings` twice; the total time taken was comparable to that with `cProfile.run()` for the slow case. So `cProfile.run()` is at least not slowing things down. There is a possibility that the fast result is tainted by `cProfile.run()`,<s>, but anecdotally for large values of `N` and `k` (`(10000, 10000)`) I noticed a perceptible difference between the first run of `bits_strings()` and the slow one later in the day</s>.
- **interpreter quirk**: I thought this could be happening because of the interpreter wrongly optimizing the generator expressions inside `chrs()` and `bits_strings()`, but this is the you-pay-for-what-you-write CPython interpreter so that seems unlikely.
- **Python 2.7 quirk**: Redefining `chrs()` (using the up-arrow to retrieve the prior definition) inconsistently does the same trick in `python3`: https://pastebin.com/Uw7PgF7i
- **Zalgo coming to exact revenge for that one time I parsed HTML with regex**: not ruled out

<s>I'm tempted to believe that `bits_strings()`, at different times (different definitions of the same function with the same code, not different runs), has actually performed differently. But I have no clue as to why that could be the case. I suspect this is related more closely to `chrs()` than it is to `bits_strings()`.</s>

I'm unclear on why redefining `chrs()` seems to be unpredictably affecting the profiler output.

Comment: Strange... the "2005005 function calls in 0.368 seconds" summary line looks fast, but if you examine the cumtime column, total execution time seems to be around 1.970 seconds.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks for noticing that. I checked my REPL logs and that was not a mispaste, so it looks like there might be a reporting bug with `cumtime` & summary in `cProfile` (or very confusing WAI behavior) on top of the confusing behavior with `<genexpr>` calls.

Looks to also have happened in the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1u1j1ZUt).

Maybe `cProfile` is somehow losing track of `N*k` `<genexpr>` calls? It could be tracking only the outer part of the `<genexpr>` (the "generate `N` random strings" part) and somehow dropping the "generate 1 `k`-length string" part in its reporting.

Comment: I suspect cProfile is getting confused by the two genexps with the exact same filename and lineno. `2001000` is the number for the genexp in `chrs` (each generator reentry counts as a call), while `1001` is the number for the genexp in `bits_strings`. Only one of the generators is showing up in the reports.

Comment: Seems like the most likely explanation to me. Do you have any ideas on how to deterministically reproduce the issue? Would like to verify and hopefully mark this question answered.

Comment: Looking through the cProfile source code, it looks like the result depends on the memory addresses of code objects, so the best way to reproduce it seems to be to just keep redefining the functions until the results change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an artifact of the cProfile results reporting, which cannot distinguish between two code objects with the same name, file name, and line number.

While gathering statistics, stats are maintained in a [randomly-rebalancing binary search tree](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Modules/rotatingtree.c), apparently a randomized splay tree variant. [Code object memory addresses are used as keys](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Modules/_lsprof.c) for Python functions (and PyMethodDef memory addresses for C functions).

However, when profiling is complete, the data is [reorganized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Lib/cProfile.py#L54) into a dict, using (file name, line number, code object name) tuples as keys for Python functions. This loses information in cases when these keys are not unique, such as your example. In such cases, the code object with the highest memory address gets processed last, so that code object is the one whose stats appear in the resulting dict.

---

In your tests, you see stats for either the genexp in `chrs` or the genexp in `bits_strings`. Which stats you see depends on which genexp's code object has a higher memory address.

If you had run your code as a script instead of interactively, the genexps would have been distinguishable by line number, and both genexps would have appeared in the result. Interactive mode restarts line numbers for each "unit" of code entered interactively (one `>>>` prompt and all following `...` prompts). However, there are still cases where this profiling artifact would occur non-interactively, such as with two genexps on the same line, or two files with the same name.